# Webview page not scrolling when keyboard comes in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I am using react-native-webview to view html. Html contains inputbox like chatwindow. If i give url to this webview in iOS it is working properly.But in android if i click on inputbox keyboard overlaps on inputbox.

code:

```
<WebView
    originWhitelist={["https://*", "http://*", "file://*", "sms://*", "tel://*"]}
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
    source={{ uri: 'http://sample.com/sample/chat.html' }} 

    scalesPageToFit={false}
    injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
    javaScriptEnabled={true} domStorageEnabled={true}
    }
>
</WebView>
```

Comment: I think you need to use https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview

Comment: inside html i have textbox, it is not considering keyboardavoidingview

Answer (score 1):

You are using percentage based sizes, and I'm going to guess that you are testing this on Android, as the default is to resize the view when the onscreen keyboard is open (It adds android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" to the main Activity in AndroidManifest.xml See this line of code in github.com/facebook/react-native )

To avoid this resize issue, you have two options -

```
Change adjustResize to adjustPan in the AndroidManifest.xml
Don't use percentage based sizes for the logo. Or if it's an Image, just set the width and allow the height to be set based on the image size.
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
 <KeyboardAvoidingView
            enabled={Platform.OS === 'android'} // auto scroll view when user focus inputs, on iOS it is already done by native OS
            behavior="padding"
            keyboardVerticalOffset={75}>
            <WebView
              {{...props}}}
              nestedScrollEnabled />
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: why `keyboardVerticalOffset`=75? I dont know

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is wrapping with 'KeyboardAvoidingView' like below

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="position" keyboardVerticalOffset={30}>
{your content}
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```